# How to show incoming call screen for my app using android SDK?

Tags: android, android-cursor, phone-call

How does WhatsApp call or other VoIP based apps show incoming call screen with photo on Android? How do I get this information of the caller to show it to the receiver? (This is not for the default phone call, it is for the call made through my app itself)

Comment: so you want to get informations of the caller from the recievers phone?

Comment: Yes, photo and name and everything. This is the caller from my voip app to the receiver of my voip app. Exactly like skype or whatsapp call feature.

Comment: you should ask your question more specific..

Answer (score 0):

As your question is very broad I can only give you a very general answer:

You could query caller's information from the phonebook via a `Cursor`. This could provide you the informations like photo or the name, if it was saved into the phonebook previously.